# Trouble with while loop in python function

Tags: python

I have a small app that asks for a movie. When the rating is over 50, return watch it. If it doesn't, choose another movie. Though when I get to the condition in movieDec, it won't go back to the top of the function to calculate the score of the movie. Can't figure this one out.

```
def getScore():
   choose = raw_input("pick a movie ")
   rt = RT()
   info = rt.search(choose)
   rating1 = info[0].get('ratings').get('critics_score')
   rating2 = info[0].get('ratings').get('audience_score')
   stars = (rating1 + rating2) / 2
   return rating1, rating2, stars


def movieDec():
   critic, aud, stars = getScore()
   print 'Critics gave it a %s' %critic
   print 'Audiences gave it a %s' %aud
   print 'The average rating is %s' %stars
   while stars < 50:
       print "That's no good, pick again"
       getScore()
    print 'Good choice.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating the `stars` variable in the loop. Try:

```
while stars < 50:
   print "That's no good, pick again"
   critic, aud, stars = getScore()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you are ignoring the return value of `getScore()`:

```
   getScore()
```

Change that to:

```
   critic, aud, stars = getScore()
```

Answer (score 0):

this corrected code [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911238/trouble-with-while-loop-in-python-function/14911270#14911270) would call getScore() function 2nd time (if stars <50) but then it won't display the scores until the loop looks like:

```
while stars < 50:
   print "That's no good, pick again"
   critic, aud, stars = getScore()
   print 'Critics gave it a %s' %critic
   print 'Audiences gave it a %s' %aud
   print 'The average rating is %s' %stars
```

Comment: Instead of printing the whole thing again, you could just call `movieDec()` again.